# Are NoneType objects deleted during list operations?

Tags: python, list, matrix, nonetype

So I am implementing several functions for the 2048 game, and have some problems with the vital, so-called `match( row )` [search for list items adjacent or separated only by `None`'s and add them at leftmost position]. My algorithm seems to work very well on its own, but when implemented as helper function it runs into some trouble. For example, the matched row is used as `[2]` or `[4,4]`, whereas it should be inputted as `[None,2,None,None]` and `[2,None,2,4]`, respectively, wherefrom my inquiry about possible NoneType object deletion.

Any light shed on this question would be very much appreciated.

Here is the full function:

```
def match(row):
    copy1 = row.copy()
    score = 0
    while None in copy1: copy1.remove(None)
    i = 0
    while i < len(copy1):
        temp = copy1[i]
        if i < len(copy1)-1 and copy1[i+1] == temp:
            row[i] = temp*2
            row[row.index(temp)] = None
            score = score + temp*2
            i = i + 2
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return row
```

Comment: You see that part near the start of the function where you specifically go through and remove Nones? Do you think that has anything to do with the problem? (Also, don't use `row.index(temp)`. It's slow, it's bug-prone in the presence of duplicates, and you should already know the index.)

Comment: I make a copy just to remove the Nones, and I assure you this function works perfectly fine if it's the only one called.

Comment: you will have to show how you are calling this function in your code. You say that it works one way and not the other so show both ways that you call the function

Comment: I think you're getting into trouble in the while loop checking for/removing `None`. Personally the code seems overly complicated for what it's trying to do.

Comment: `i` in `row` and `copy1` will not be related, which is likely a source of some of your problems. You read `copy1[i]` and write a computed value to `row[i]`, but all the removed `None`s mean that the indices in `row` are only tangentially related to `copy1` at best. Beyond that, you've turned removing `None`s from `list` into a `O(n**2)` operation, when it should only be `O(n)`; `copy1 = [x for x in row if x is not None]` would both copy and strip the `None`s in a single pass, with the cost being proportionate to the length of `row`, not the length of `row` and the number of `None`s in it.

Comment: Might also be useful to see the supposedly working non-helper function version. Code this ugly seems likely to be the result of really poor refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative implementation of the same function. It becomes much cleaner if you don't reuse the `row` variable and use a separate index for `trimmed` and `new_row`.

```
def match(row):
    trimmed = list(filter(None, row))
    new_row = [None] * 4
    score = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(trimmed):
        temp = trimmed[i]
        if i + 1 < len(trimmed) and trimmed[i + 1] == temp:
            new_row[j] = temp * 2
            score += temp * 2
            i += 1
        else:
            new_row[j] = temp
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return new_row
```